# ObjectInputStream readObject in while Loop

Tags: java, compiler-errors, objectinputstream

Is it possible to read from `ObjectInputStream` in while loop which will terminate by exception thrown by socket timeout `socket.setSoTimeout(4000);`

```
while(Object obj = ois.readObject()) {  <-- Not Working
//do something with object    
}
```

Comment: @YassinHajaj Don't you think readObject will wait forever if socket is alive??

Comment: I really do not know. It should be tested...

Comment: well readObject is blocking

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
while(Object obj = ois.readObject()) {  <-- Not Working
//do something with object    
}
```

When you say 'not working', what you really mean is 'not compiling', for reasons that are stated in the compiler message: `Object` isn't a `boolean` expression, and you can't declare a variable in a `while` condition.

However the code isn't valid anyway. The correct way to read to end of stream of an arbitrary `ObjectInputStream` is catch `EOFException`, for example as follows:

```
try
{
    for (;;)
    {
        Object object = in.readObject();
        // ...
    }
}
catch (SocketTimeoutException exc)
{
    // you got the timeout
}
catch (EOFException exc)
{
    // end of stream
}
catch (IOException exc)
{
    // some other I/O error: print it, log it, etc.
    exc.printStackTrace(); // for example
}
```

Note that the suggestion in comments to test the `readObject()` return value for `null` is *not* correct. It will only return `null` if you wrote a `null`.

Comment: Can you loop in.readObject(); Does it not then read the same object mutliple times?

Comment: @Lealo No, of course it doesn't return the same thing multiple times. What read method does that?

Answer (score 0):

This is not working because the statement was written inside while() is not a boolean expression, So we can write this as below:

```
Object obj = null;
while ((obj = ois.readObject()) != null) {
//do something with object  
}
```