# After reading list containing objects using ObjectInputStream how to iterate through the list?

Tags: java, list, object, iteration, objectinputstream

I have a binary file having some `list` where each `list` has group of similar `objects`
I am using `ObjectInputStream` to read the `list` series one by one
Now, instead of directly printing the `list` I want to `iterate` through the `list` and print the elements separately.

Following is my code -

```
class ReadObject54 {
    public static void readObject(String filename) {
        try (ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(filename))) {
            Object obj = null;
            boolean cond = true;
            while(cond) {
                try {
                    obj = ois.readObject();
                } catch (EOFException e) {
                    break;
                }
                if(obj == null) {
                    cond = false;
                } else {
                    System.out.println(obj);
                }
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Here the `obj` is reading series of `list` from a binary file. 
Each `list` has similar `objects`
But different `list` have different `objects` 
Here I am using `System.out.println(obj)` to directly print the list 
But instead I want to `iterate` through the list and print the elements separately
How to do so?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ObjectInputStream readObject in while Loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33135298/objectinputstream-readobject-in-while-loop)

Comment: Same way you would iterate any other `List`, after casting the object. Unclear what the problem is.

Comment: @user207421 thank you so much, actually I'm studying this portion since only two days and Java from total basic since only 2 months. Prior that I had zero knowledge of Java. The casting thing plain went out of my mind. :-)